# How to add new line character in following code?

Tags: asp.net, sql, string

When i inserting the data in database then there is facility to the user that in multiline textbox he can write sentence in multiple line.
So when i am populating the same data the database it populate the data like this : fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff<br />  f<br />  f<br />  f<br />  f<br />  f<br />  f<br />  f<br />  f<br />  <br />  ff<br />  f<br />  f<br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  fff

but i want to remove &lt, &gt ,br. For this i have used following code but my purpose is not solved. So how to do that:

```
txtEditorOpportunity.Text = dbReader["DESCRIPTION"].ToString().Replace("<br/>", "\n");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a space in the `<br />` tag in your question, so while using `Replace` method. Try it like

```
.Replace("<br />", "\n");
```

Note the space character between br and / which makes it `<br />` and NOT `<br/>`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it correctly. Just observe the tags that you are getting, they contain a space between "". So make sure that you put a space in your replace command accordingly.
Something like this.

```
.Replace("<br />", "\n");
```

Some browsers treat `<br />` as just `<br>`, so to be sure that nothing goes wrong, you can replace the above code with the following code.

```
.Replace("<br />", "\n").Replace("<br>", "\n");
```